# Clean architechture Entities depending on entities

Tags: python, clean-architecture

I am writing a python application following Robert Cecil Martin's Clean Architechture book. I have the following entities:

```
@dataclass
class Factory():
    name: str
    latitude: float
    longitude: float


@dataclass
class Event():
    message: str
    timestamp: datetime
    source: Factory
```

I have also implemented a repository interface, `ReadOnlyRepository`, to read both types of entities from a database.

Due to the dependency rule, I understand that my entities should not store IDs of any kind.

**The Problem**

My current repository implementations (`EventRepository`, `FactoryRepository`) communicate with a PostgreSQL database in which I store the `source` field of my `Event` entity as an integer. The only way I can think of to get an `Event` from `EventRepository` is to use the stored source id and then use `FactoryRepository` to get the `Factory` entity. I'm sure this is not the intended way to access my data (no single responsibility, excess calls to the database, etc.), but I haven't found any way to solve this implementation issue.

I'm thinking I could try to get rid of the `source`field in `Event`, but the idea does not convince me. How can I get an `Event` entity without calling the `FactoryRepository`? Am I understanding something wrong about the entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dependency Rule does not forbit storing an ID inside of your entities. The Dependency Rules just says that inner layers should not have (compile) dependencies to the outer layers and from my perspective an ID field does not create such a dependency.

Furthermore, Clean Architecture does not require you to create one repository per entity, in fact the opposite is recommended: repositories should provide exactly those APIs the application logic demands. So you could/should just create exactly the query API you need to get the Events you want given the query criteria you have.

For more details on how to implement repository pattern correctly in Clean Architecture see [Repository Pattern: CORRECT vs. pragmatic? | Clean Architecture](https://youtu.be/pfhDO_hZixw)